# Function pointer assignment cause error after creating DLL

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I written a class for my application. in this class there is static function pointer that used for communication over network socket. at startup, i assign this function pointer to a function outside of the class and work fine without any problem.
now i created DLL from my class, but when i assign this pointer to my function, i got "unresolved external symbol" error.
how i can assign static function pointer inside class to a function outside of class without any problem?

here is my class:

(header, "MyClass.h")

```
#define IMPORT_DLL

#ifdef IMPORT_DLL
    #define DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport) 
#else
    #define DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) 
#endif

namespace nmspace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        //Constructors
        DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT MyClass();
        DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT MyClass(size_t ID);

        //Destructor
        DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT ~MyClass();

        ....

        //This static function pointer should be assigned to a function outside of class
        //this pointer used frequently
        static bool(*Class_Transmit)(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port);
    }
}
```

(source, "MyClass.cpp")

```
#include "MyClass.h"

bool(*MyClass::Class_Transmit)(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port) = nullptr;

//Constructor
void MyClass::MyClass()
{
    size_t Sock_num = 0
    uint8_t TX_buffer[20] = "Transmit done";
    bool is_connected = false;
    is_connected = Class_Transmit(TX_buffer, 20, Sock_num);
}
```

(main, "main.cpp")

```
#include "MyClass.h"

bool MyFunc(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port)
{
    ....
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("myclass.dll"));

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.
    if (hinstLib != NULL)
        return false;


    //Assign network socket function for "Class_Transmit" class for communication
    MyClass::Class_Transmit = MyFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static bool (__cdecl* 
nmspace::MyClass::Class_Transmit)(unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int)"
 (?Class_Transmit@MyClass@nmspace@@2P6A_NPAEII@ZA)
```

Comment: *i got "unresolved external symbol" error.* -- Please post the exact error message.  Also please post the *exact* prototype of the function you are supplying the callback to.

Comment: Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static bool (__cdecl* nmspace::MyClass::Class_Transmit)(unsigned char *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?Class_Transmit@MyClass@nmspace@@2P6A_NPAEII@ZA)

Comment: `nmspace::MyClass::` -- So is this function in the `nmspace` namespace?  Also, you should update the original question with the error information, and not in the comment section.

Comment: i added "using namespace nmspace" at top of main.cpp file

Comment: No, that does not put that function *in* the namespace.

Comment: @RodgerBrown You may want to add some Visual C++ tags since DLLs and __declspec are not part of the C++ language. As to the link error, you probably want to mark `Class_Transmit` as `DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT`.

Comment: You *must* use either `void nmspace::MyClass::MyClass() { ... }` or `namespace nmspace { void MyClass::MyClass() { ... } }`. Same with the static member variable definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the function needs to be in the `nmspace` namespace.  Try the following:

```
namespace nmspace
{
    bool MyFunc(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After doing that, you need to clean up the rest of the declarations.  The following full program compiles and links with no issues:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace nmspace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            static bool (*Class_Transmit)(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port);
    };
}

bool (*nmspace::MyClass::Class_Transmit)(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port) = nullptr;


namespace nmspace
{
    bool MyFunc(uint8_t* TX_buffer, size_t TX_size, size_t Port)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    nmspace::MyClass::Class_Transmit = nmspace::MyFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried but not worked, same error; thanks for your help Paul

Comment: `MyFunc` doesn't have to be in the `nmspace` namespace, but the `MyClass` members definitely must be.